# How to follow a moving target using Godot NavigationAgent2D?

Tags: godot, navmesh

I am currently creating an enemy which will follow the player.

I was using the player GlobalPosition to calculate the direction of the enemy movement. I am now in the process of implementing obstacles in my map and I used a NavMesh and NavigationAgent to handle moving around obstacles.

When trying to update the navigation path each frame, the enemy seemed to move slightly left and right but ultimately getting stuck in the same position (see note below).

My question is: how should I handle updating the path towards the player? If I update the path per frame, the enemy does not seem to move towards the player (as just described), it might also imply performance issues, and if I take too long to update the path, the enemy moves towards a stale/outdated location.

PS. A tile map is being used to generate the NavMesh. In order to stop enemies getting stuck on corners, we are using this "[solution](https://www.reddit.com/r/godot/comments/x7s4z1/guide_for_how_to_fix_navigationagents_getting/)" I noticed that when this "solution" is not used, updating the path per frame works as expected.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution @Zeruno?